# Setting up Toshiba e-Studio 5005AC on 18.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, toshiba

Just got into a new office, where there are two printers: 4505ac and 5005ac from Toshiba. There are no drivers available (in the database) for these models. Also I need to enter a department code somewhere?

On a previous version of Ubuntu, it is quite possible to setup a Toshiba e studio - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh6nL4oVVHQ

On the official website with drivers - http://business.toshiba.com/support/downloads/index.html?model=5005ac it says there are Linux Filter Color drivers, which I honestly do not know how to install:
[image: Toshiba]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, you need to follow these steps:

1. Download a CUPS filter, any of these two options:

[image]

First download link is [this one](http://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/16768/TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.tar), and the second is [this one](http://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/16769/TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.tar).

2. Decompress the tar files using the following command:

> ```
> tar xvf TOSHIBA_ColorMFP_CUPS.tar --absolute-names
> ```

3. Create queue (manually)

a. Enter the following command:

> `ls /opt/toshiba/tap/interface`

b. If the above directory does not exist, enter the following command:

> `mkdir /opt/toshiba/tap/interface`

c. Log on to the root account.

```
sudo su
```

d. Open your UNIX/Linux editor.
e. Create the following file.

```
/opt/toshiba/tap/interface/<queue name>.conf
```

f. Add a line as below in the .conf.

```
dest=<IP address>
```

g. Save the file.
h. Enter the following command:
Color MFP:

```
cp /opt/toshiba/tap/model/net_estcolor /opt/toshiba/tap/interface/<queue name>
```

i. Enter the following command:

```
/opt/toshiba/tap/bin/modPrintcap -a <queue name> <IP address>
```

j. Enter the following command:

```
ls /opt/toshiba/tap/bin/flag_<queue name>
```

Then you should try to print.

More info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139624

[Official Installation Manual](http://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/14345/Inst_Guide_EN_(EBN)_Ver01F.pdf)

Comment: Where do I enter my department code for this printer?

Comment: " j. Enter the following command "Does not work, error: "ls: cannot access '/opt/toshiba/tap/bin/flag_q1': No such file or directory"

Comment: Also there is no printer added in printers.

Answer (score 1):

Philippe Delteil's solution didn't work for for the CUPS filter.  Instead I downloaded the [linux.tar](http://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/16241/linux.tar) filter and followed some of his instructions:

```
$ sudo tar xvf linux.tar --absolute-names
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/toshiba/tap/interface
```

Then I did steps 3c through 3i above in Philippe Delteil's instructions and printing worked.

Comment: I'm glad it helped (a bit)